# The curvature and torsion of the tangent indicatrix

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curvature

Let $\alpha$ be a unit speed curve.  Its tangent indicatrix $\sigma$  is defined by $\sigma(t)=T(t)$.  Find torsion and curvature of $\sigma$ with respect to the torsion and curvature of $\alpha$.

There is an answer  on my book. But I don't understand (*) part

$$ \kappa_\sigma=\frac{\|\sigma'\times \sigma''\|}{\|\sigma'\|^3}$$

$$ \tau_\sigma=\frac{\left<\sigma'\times\sigma'',\sigma'''\right>}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|^2} 
$$

$$\sigma'(t)=T'(t) \Rightarrow \sigma'=T'=\kappa N$$

....

We find $\sigma'\times\sigma''=\kappa^3B+\kappa^2\tau  T$

$$\|\sigma'\|=\sqrt{\left<\sigma',\sigma'\right>}=\sqrt{\left<\kappa N,\kappa N\right>}={\kappa^2\left<N,N\right>}=|\kappa|=\|\alpha''\|$$

$$\|\sigma'\times\sigma''\|=\sqrt{(\kappa^2\tau)^2+(\kappa^3)^2}=\kappa^2\sqrt{\tau^2+\kappa^2} \tag{*}$$

$$\kappa_\sigma=\frac{\sqrt{\tau^2+\kappa^2}}{\kappa}$$

...

I couldn't understand the equation (*). Can you explain it please?
(The expression "tangents indicator" may  not be well translated. I translated into English and $\kappa$ is the curvature and $\tau$ , $T$ tangent vector, and $B=T\times N$.)

Comment: $B$ and $T$ are orthogonal unit vectors. You know that $\|a+b\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$ if $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal, right? Apply it to $\|\sigma'\times\sigma''\| = \|\kappa^3B+\kappa^2\tau T\|$.

Comment: In English this is called the *tangent indicatrix*. Your $x$s need to be written as '\times' :)

Comment: @RahulNarain thanks. appreciated.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. Could you suggest me a book or an article about this subject?

Comment: You just have to use the formulas for curvature/torsion of non-arclength parametrized curves. The tangent indicatrix appears in curve theory, but only as a tool. What book are you studying from?

Comment: @lyme How did you get $\sigma'\times\sigma''=\kappa^3B+\kappa^2\tau  T$ ?

Comment: @lyme Could you post the solution for the torsion, or mention which reference you are using so I can have a look?

Comment: @lyme Also, I think the torsion formula is actually $ \tau_\sigma=\frac{\left<\sigma'\times\sigma''',\sigma''\right>}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|^2} $. If anyone could help with this, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a different definition for the torsion (which is the same except for the sign), so that's the reason why I've got a different formula to prove. But still no progress with this proof.