# Curvature and Torsion of tangent indicatrix

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm trying to find the curvature and torsion of the tangent indicatrix of a curve with respect to the curvature and torsion of the initial curve, that is, if $\kappa, \tau$ are the curvature and torsion of $\alpha(s)$, what is the curvature and torsion of $\beta(s) = \alpha'(s)$?
 I'm aware of [The curvature and torsion of the tangent indicatrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626973/the-curvature-and-torsion-of-the-tangent-indicatrix)
However, I don't understand how do you get $\sigma'\times\sigma''=\kappa^3B+\kappa^2\tau  T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's simple:
$$\sigma' = \kappa N$$
$$\sigma'' = \kappa'N-\kappa^2T+\kappa\tau B$$
Thus
$$\sigma' \times \sigma'' = \kappa^3B+\kappa^2\tau T$$